# Is there a way to intergrate vBulletin into PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, vbulletin

What im wanting to achive is intergrating vBulletin into a PHP page, or what ever. Im not wanting to re-create a skin that looks like the site, im more or less wanting the forum to be 100% intergrated with the site, now obviously the skin would need to change etc so it looked the part, but how would i intergrate it, iframes wouldn't be able to handle it would it?
Ross

Answer (score 5):

It might be easier to integrate your PHP page into vBulletin than trying to integrate vBulletin into your PHP page.

Then you can just do something like this in a PHP file in your forum root (or change paths as required):

```
// ######################## SET PHP ENVIRONMENT ###########################
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// ##################### DEFINE IMPORTANT CONSTANTS #######################
define('THIS_SCRIPT', 'myscript'); 

// #################### PRE-CACHE TEMPLATES AND DATA ######################
// get special phrase groups
$phrasegroups = array();

// get special data templates from the datastore
$specialtemplates = array();

// pre-cache templates used by all actions
$globaltemplates = array('MYPAGE');

// pre-cache templates used by specific actions
$actiontemplates = array();

// ########################## REQUIRE BACK-END ############################
require_once('./global.php');

// ... your PHP code goes here
// ... you can use vBulletin's database classes and security mechanisms in your page
// ... you can also use vBulletin's headers/footers and other templates too
// example (assuming you've already created a template called MYPAGE):

eval('print_output("' . fetch_template('MYPAGE') . '");');
```

Comment: True. And PHP is supported in majority of the page templates anyway. There are hundreds of tutorials on VBORG

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to do this is to redefine the `$header` and `$footer` variables in a plugin `global_setup_complete` or similar.

For example, if you already have a header.php file from another system:

```
ob_start();
include('/path/to/your/header/file.php');
$header = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); 

ob_start();
include('/path/to/your/footer/file.php');
$footer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

This would load the output of those files into the `$header` and `$footer` variables.